# Microsoft Sync Framework COM class error

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I have been playing with "Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1" to sync two local sql server 2008 databases with an asp.net project.

my code:

```
SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=XXXXXX;User ID=sa; Password=xxxx;Database=ZzzClient");

SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection("Server=XXXXXX;User ID=sa; Password=xxxx;Database=ZzzServer");

SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("InventoryScope", clientConn);
syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("InventoryScope", serverConn);

syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

but I get following error when the **Synchronize()** call is executed;

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

developing envoriement VS 2012, C# asp.net project, framework 4.5
OS:windows 7 Home Prem. (x64)

SyncSDK-v2.1-x64-ENU was installed.

Microsoft.Synchronization

Microsoft.Synchronization.Data

Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer

references were added to project from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime".

Both databases provisioned by SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.

I've tried Project Platform Target both x64 ans x86

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated....

[image: Provisioned databases]

**I've changed the all references from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Sync Framework" to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime"**

[image: new references]

**And set the Platform Target to x64**
[image: Platform Target]

**"Use Local IIS Web Server" is selected**
[image: Local IIS]

**UPDATE:**
I tried same process with a console application and it worked properly and synchronized all data.

I added following four references to console application;

"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\x64\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll"

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\ADO.NET\V3.1\x64\Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.dll"

"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\ADO.NET\V3.1\x64\Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server.dll"

"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\ADO.NET\V3.1\x64\Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.dll"

and set the application's debug properties as following 
[image: console application's properties]

Same references, same build properties(target to x64) and same code does not work for in Asp.Net project.

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication2' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

i guess, web application can't load correct assemblies and tries to load x86 versions

Comment: shouldn't the reference assemblies be in Program Files instead of Program Files (x86)? are you running it in IIS or the VS web server?

Comment: I tried both. If I add these references via the VS add-reference, it comes from Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime. I manually deleted the "Program Files (x86)" one and added new one with browsing from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\x64. Same result....

Comment: VS 2012 shows and adds "Microsoft.Synchronization" assembly from "Program Files (x86)" but instead of that if I manually add assembly from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\x64" , i get "Could not load file or assembly 'DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." error.

Comment: is your IIS running in 64-bit?

Comment: yes it is on the same OS which is "Windows 7 Home Prem. (x64)". Assemblies work on WindowsForms App. and Console App. properly but the asp.net.

Comment: if i start the project without debugging(ctrl+F5) it works and syncs the databases..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions:

> If you start an asp.net project which has x64 Sync Framework
>   assemblies but you are **NOT** running Visual Studio under the
>   administrator account, VS can not load Snyc Framework assemblies. At
>   least, that's my problem..

**If you are not administrator VS can not manage "Local IIS Web Server" properly.**

Also if I'm not wrong, "IIS Express" can not load x64 Sync Framework assemblies even if your OS is x64.

> Do not bother to use "IIS express" just use "Local IIS Web Server"
>   with administrator rights on VS and set platform target x64 for your project.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use the 64bit Sync Framework DLLs and had to change my C# app properties from building for *Any CPU* to *x64* in the project properties build page.
But then the GUI designer did not show dialogs any more.

The alternative was to use the 32bit Sync Framework and set *Prefer 32bit* in the build settings of the project.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens in a computer different to your dev machine, be sure you have installed the Microsoft Sync Framework - Redistributable Package.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19502

And choose the right the platform in the download options (x86-x64)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your target platform and want to keep it "Any". Use a new application pool for your application,go to advance settings and change Enable 32-bit application as True. It worked for me, it may work for you.

[image]